# Android -get image from URL without being saved to storage

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I get a image from a server an I want to display it in my Adapter.

Even if i use URL with Glide or if I use the conversion URL->BITMAP->URI,
the image gets saved in gallery.How can i get it displayed without being saved?
Or how can i save it as nomedia and then use it with Glide/Picasso?

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
  String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
  return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

Comment: what's the output when image downloaded?

Comment: You can use the Glide. You can easily pass Url of the image and it will show the image. In glide you can configure whether you need to cache the image or not. Even you cache the image, it will not show in the gallary

Answer (score 1):

This will load an image from the server and it won't appear in the galley.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(IMAGE_URL)
    .into(imageView);
```

As for caching, that's what we can find in Glide's docs:

> The default strategy, AUTOMATIC, tries to use the optimal strategy for local and remote images. AUTOMATIC will store only the unmodified data backing your load when you’re loading remote data (like from URLs) because downloading remote data is expensive compared to resizing data already on disk. For local data AUTOMATIC will store the transformed thumbnail only because retrieving the original data is cheap if you need to generate a second thumbnail size or type.

It doesn't matter whether you use caching or not, the image won't be visible in the gallery.